# How to efficiently flatten folders?

Tags: file-transfer, files-and-directories

I have 100 folders each with 1 million images, is there any (efficient) Mathematica command to flatten them into a single folder with 100 million files?

Iterating and doing CopyFile and DeleteFile seems wrong...

Comment: I would use [`Run`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html) with a shell command that does the file copying.

Comment: Sure I know how to do this on Linux, I’m asking for MMA

Comment: You could try using RenameFile, changing each of the 100 folders to the new one.

Comment: Would that move or copy things?

Comment: It moves. So might be fast.